# Got Error while implementing FacebookSDK 3.0 hackBook example in Iphone application "FBSettings.h file not found"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, facebook

I added all required frameworks [using facebook developers guide line](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/getting-started-with-the-ios-sdk/#coding) but I still got the same error:
`FBSettings.h file not found`

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: Show us the code of the class or point of your application that is giving this error.

Comment: i solve this prob i am Implementing  new facebooksdk but because  i can not able to login from facebook app its just open facebook app and when i select ok then got only my app login screen

my solution is that:-
i added this in my Appdeleget without any changes

**- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    return [self.facebook handleOpenURL:url];
}**
and Running Cool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many ways to solve this Problem. 
First check in your directory or Project that this file is available or not. if not available then
1) Download all the Modules from Git individually.

Now, you have confirmed that the "FBSettings.h" file is available in your project directory then just write the header file like below.
Means write the full path of the "FBSettings.h" file from directory and it will work extremely Fine.

Ex. here,

```
#import "../directoryName/FBSettings.h"
```